# T-SQL - having arithmetic deficiency syndrome

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (CID int, C1 varchar(5), C2 decimal(18,6), C3 decimal(18,6))
INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT 1,'A',0.0,0.0
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'A',0.1,0.0
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'A',0.1,0.1
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'B',0.0,0.0
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'B',0.1,0.0
UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'B',0.1,0.1

SELECT * FROM @Table
WHERE C1 NOT IN ('B') AND (C2 >= 0 AND C3 >= 0)

/* Desired output
CID     C1      C2      C3
1       A       0.0     0.0
2       A       0.1     0.0
3       A       0.1     0.1
4       B       0.0     0.0
*/
```

If C2 and C3 are greater than 0 then no record with C1 = B should be returned. I'm having trouble figuring out the logic. I can't seem to figure out the arithmetic. :(

Thank you

p.s. a non-subquery sln would be awesome!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE NOT ( C1 = 'B' AND (C2 > 0 or C3 > 0))`, probably

Comment: The logic you have suggested negates the desired output. Your query does imply the logic correctly, I think you need to re-think your logic again.

Comment: @ASh Please post answers in the answers area, not the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is: "do not include the record if `C2 > 0 AND C3 > 0 AND C1 = 'B'`"

Negate it, which results in: `C2 <= 0 OR C3 <= 0 OR C1 <> 'B'` and use this condition to include all of the *other* records.

Note, if you meant to exclude records where `(C2 > 0 OR C3 > 0) AND C1 = 'B'`, then you would negate that to include the other records: `(C2 <= 0 AND C3 <= 0) OR C1 <> 'B'`

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the OR part. sln looks right.
Update: oops, getting 5 records instead of 4. I think it's the OR b/w C2 and C3.

Comment: Well, consider the first statement.  Is your logic to exclude a record based on if *both* C2 and C3 are greater than 0, or is it if one or the other (or both) is greater than 0?

Answer (score 1):

Inclusive, consider the rows you do want:

```
SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE (C1 NOT IN ('B')) OR (C2 <= 0 AND C3 <= 0)
```

Exclusive, consider the rows you do not want:

```
SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE NOT (C1 IN ('B') AND (C2 > 0 OR C3 > 0))
```

These are algebraically equivalent, so pick the one that reads best.

Comment: The first query meets the req but the second doesn't. Why is it the same? Trying to figure out the logic of the first query... lol